# google map v2 throws no found class error of rstylable

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

i have successfully followed all the process to start the the google map v2,
but at runtime it through class not found error,
how to get out of this stuff

here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment

        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {


  private GoogleMap map;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_location);

    map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

  }



}
```

logcat

```
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:271)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:558)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.curioussolutions.autoistdiary.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
02-20 11:44:56.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 11:44:56.613: W/jdwp(1394): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
```

do reply ,thank you

Comment: which part of my code you have editd

Comment: Try to remove the line `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` from your layout and then test.

Comment: no it doesnt hlp me,same error again